# Steering angle is several degrees off on the steering rack - 2014 BMW F01

Tags: bmw, steering

I have a 2014 BMW F01 (750d xDrive). It keeps pulling to the right and I initially thought the car needed an alignment. I got an alignment at a local shop, but the problem persisted.

I went to the BMW dealership and they began troubleshooting:

1. They replaced MacPherson struts.
2. Replaced the MacPherson mounting assembly.
3. Did 3 more alignments.
4. Changed from the summer 20" wheels/tires to the winter 18" wheels/tires.

After all of that, the problem still persisted. The BMW dealer couldn't tell me how we can fix it. I finally took it to a mechanic that worked on race cars and he told me that the angle on the (electronic) steering rack was something to the tune of 6 degrees off. He said that it's electronically controlled and he can't program it, because it might cause some other issues. He thought that the risk of other issues, and the potential cost of fixing them, is too great for the inconvenience of the constant pulling.

Any ideas on how this problem can be solved? Has anybody had this problem before?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Wow, that sounds inconvenient! First, I'm surprised the BMW dealer didn't figure it out. Second, I'd bet they can fix it through reprogramming it. The dealership should have ways of fixing something like this without causing the separate issues the mechanic talked about. It may/may not be the service writer who could tell you if they can do it. Most are *NOT* that knowledgeable. Hopefully someone on here might be able to say from first hand knowledge whether or not they can.

Comment: "Any ideas on how this problem can be solved? " I thought the race car mechanic told you what the solution is? There is no workaround for this.

Comment: are the dealer telling you that they are unable to re program/reset the steering controller in your 6 years old car,https://www.youcanic.com/wiki/bmw-steering-angle-sensor-calibration

Comment: Thanks all. I'm in Bulgaria and the local BMW dealers are not the best. They spent a lot of time trying to figure out the issue, but they couldn't. They also called the "central" dealership in Germany, in order to get help (imagine remote troubleshooting). That didn't seem to work. 

The dealer did tell me that they can "fix" the issue by programming the car to compensate for the problem. The way he made it sound (twice) is that when they compensate for it, it won't actually be "fixed" but it would be "masked."

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The dealer is in Bulgaria, so they're not the best BMW dealer you can find in Europe. They did call the official representatives in Germany, but they seem to have really slow communication and it's almost like Germany has to do remote troubleshooting for them. The officials from Germany tell them to try something, the mechanics in Bulgaria try it, they report back to the Germans, and then they wait for more instructions. Not very fun!

Comment: @Moab The race car mechanic did say that the solution is to re-program the electronic steering rack, but there was a risk that (and I'm paraphrasing) BMW's computer can reject it and I'd have to replace the entire electronic steering rack. He said that replacing the rack can be very expensive. I just wanted to see if others have had a similar problem or a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @trondhansen I've seen that article before... I'll see if I can find somebody locally that has experience with calibrating the steering angle sensor before. Thanks for your advice! Hopefully, it works.